# C# How to convert int to hex string

Tags: c#

I've found a few articles on StackOverflow about this question, but they are all either slightly different or don't work for whatever reason. So my question to you is this: How do I convert a int into a hex string. Thanks

Edit: I've stuffed up, stupid mistake. Basically my brain melted and didnt realise that 0x0054 is 80 in decimal. :P Sorry...

Comment: So show us what you've already tried

Comment: what you have tried? are you able to show any of the incomplete example that you see in stackoverflow regarding this question? and kindly include the error or exception that you faced

Comment: @JanR It is not a duplicate as the answer to that question does not work!

Comment: @LachlanMather can you show some code please then? So that we can help you?

Answer (score 1):

```
string hexa = into_variable.ToString("X")
```

Easy solution

Answer (score 0):

```
int myInt = 1992;
string myHex = myInt.ToString("X");
```

Comment: Please explain your answer